# TextVIew doesn't appear or doesn't get added to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Here is the code of main activity. I added TextView in addJoke() method, but it doesn't appear in LinearLayout. please solve.

```
package edu.calpoly.android.lab2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdvancedJokeList extends Activity {
    private static int i=0;
    //protected String m_strAuthorName;
    protected ArrayList<Joke> m_arrJokeList=new ArrayList<Joke>();
    //protected JokeListAdapter m_jokeAdapter;

    /**
     * ViewGroup used for maintaining a list of Views that each display Jokes.
     **/
    protected LinearLayout m_vwJokeLayout;
    protected EditText m_vwJokeEditText;
    protected Button m_vwJokeButton;
    protected int m_nDarkColor;
    protected int m_nLightColor;
    /**
     * Filter Options Submenu constants
     */
    protected static final int FILTER_OPTIONS = 1;
    protected static final int LIKE = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    protected static final int DISLIKE = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    protected static final int UNRATED = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    protected static final int SHOW_ALL = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initLayout();
        String[] jokestring=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.jokeList);    
        for(String str : jokestring) 
        {
                Joke j=new Joke();
                j.setJoke(str);
                addJoke(j);
        }
        initAddJokeListeners();
    }

    protected void addJokeImplementation(){
        String strJoke=m_vwJokeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!strJoke.equals(""))
        {
        Joke joke=new Joke();
        joke.setJoke(strJoke);
        addJoke(joke);
        }
    }

    protected void initLayout() {
        setContentView(R.layout.advanced);
        m_vwJokeLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.jokeListViewGroup);
        m_vwJokeEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.newJokeEditText);
        m_vwJokeButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addJokeButton);
    }

    protected void initAddJokeListeners() {
        // TODO
        m_vwJokeEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v,int keyCOde, KeyEvent event){
                if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    if(keyCOde==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
                    {
                        addJokeImplementation();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        m_vwJokeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //Implement code to add a new joke here...
                addJokeImplementation();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void addJoke(Joke joke) {
         if(!m_arrJokeList.contains(joke))
          {
            m_arrJokeList.add(joke);
            //I also added textview here this one also
            //doesn't appear in Emulator layout, wondering whats wrong?;
            TextView TV=new TextView(this);
            TV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TV.setText(joke.toString());
            m_vwJokeLayout.addView(TV);
            m_nDarkColor=getResources().getColor(R.color.dark);
            m_nLightColor=getResources().getColor(R.color.light);       
            if(i==0)
            {
                TV.setBackgroundColor(m_nLightColor);
                i=1;
            }
            else
            {
                TV.setBackgroundColor(m_nDarkColor);
                i=0;
            }
            m_vwJokeEditText.setText("");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_vwJokeEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
          }
    }         

    /**
     * Method used to retrieve Jokes from online server. The getJoke script
     * takes a single optional parameter, which should be encode in "UTF-8".
     * This parameter allows tells script to only retrieve Jokes whose author
     * name matches the value in the parameter.
     * 
     * param-1) "author": The author of the joke.
     * 
     * URL: http://simexusa.com/aac/getJokes.php?
     * 
     */
    protected void getJokesFromServer() {
        // TODO
    }

    /**
     * This method uploads a single Joke to the server. This method should test
     * the response from the server and display success or failure to the user
     * via a Toast Notification
     * 
     * The addJoke script on the server requires two parameters, both of which
     * should be encode in "UTF-8":
     * 
     * param-1) "joke": The text of the joke.
     * 
     * param-2) "author": The author of the joke.
     * 
     * URL: http://simexusa.com/aac/addJoke.php?
     * 
     * @param joke
     *            The Joke to be uploaded to the server.
     * 
     */
    protected void uploadJokeToServer(Joke joke) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Here is  advanced.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addJokeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Joke"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newJokeEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Joke"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/jokeListViewGroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: Modified code a little bit, added Layout.params() but still TextView doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved....

I was very stupid....This was so silly....
I forgot to add android:orientation="vertical" for the root element..see the code.

I got so used to Stackoverflow....I became lazy

Thank you all great developers who gave some good tips along with the answer each time I asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons; You need to set the height and width of your TV view, either directly or by using layout params, and then after you've done this you need to call setContentView again but since the layout your adding it to is a child of the root layout, you may need to get a reference to the root layout then add the TV view to the appropriate child layout and then setContentView(root layout).

Comment: is it really needed to call again setContentView() if the view tree is always the same (even if with some more "leaves")?

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentence....I have added TextView to child of root Layout....Is this the problem?

Comment: I have given reference to the child layout and added the TextView widget, see code, but still it doesn't appear...Is it necessary to set height and width params when dynamically adding the TextView?

Comment: This error crept in 04:06:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected forward command for device emulator-555
4: device not found
04:06:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected command to check status of view server
on device emulator-5554
04:06:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected command to start view server on device
emulator-5554
04:06:07 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected command to start view server on device
emulator-5554
04:06:07 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device emulator-5554                                                       emulator 5554 is android 1.6

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check *if* your view is present at all, you will be glad to use the Hierarchy-viewer. Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

It shows you all Views present, and how they're placed. That should help you a lot with debugging like this!

Comment: I tried to use heirarchyviewer but it gives an error that adb.exe is not found...I think this is because of the new SDK R8...The adb location is changed to platform-tools....Any solution..Please help.

Comment: Yep, you should add that dir to your path. Shameless link to my blog about that with solution :)  http://androblip.huiges.nl/2011/01/10/hierarchy-viewer-problems/

Comment: Another error 04:06:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected forward command for device emulator-555
4: device not found
04:06:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected command to check status of view server
on device emulator-5554
04:06:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected command to start view server on device
emulator-5554
04:06:07 E/hierarchyviewer: Adb rejected command to start view server on device
emulator-5554
04:06:07 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device emulator-5554 emulator-5554 is android 1.6

Comment: For any who see this ABD rejected message, the most likely cause is that something else is connected to the emulator. I had started the application from Eclipse using Debug rather than Run.